# How to access objects from AppDelegate without affecting memory management?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have several view controller objects each can take in some user inputs from UITextField, save inputs to mutable arrays and display in a UITableView.

I also want these mutable arrays to be saved in files when home button is pressed by the user, so I found the code below in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

It seems this method is perfect for saving user data whenever the user presses home button, but my question is how do I access these mutable arrays declared in different view controllers in order to save them into files? I can certainly make pointers in AppDelegate and make them point to each view controller object, but I know views can be unloaded when the program is running low on memory; therefore, if I make these pointers in AppDelegate then these view objects can never be unloaded when the memory is running low(because of strong references). What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general design pattern for user interfaces is the model view controller.  The data storage ('model') is held in a separate object to the view controller.

For example, you can create an object that stores all of your applications data, instantiate it in the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and store the reference  in a property of your AppDelegate. Then each view controller can use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.myData` to retrieve the reference.

Comment: Do I need to import anything before I call [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.myData ?

Comment: Yes, you need to #import "myAppDelegate.h" (or whatever your appDelegate class name is) at the start of the view controller.  You will also need to #import "myModelObject.h" so that your view controller knows about the methods and properties of the model object

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the MVC (model/view/controller) religion. Don't mix model (the NSMutableArrays) with controller (UIViewController). If you keep all the model data in separate classes then you don't have to worry about whether the view controllers exist or not. Also, it becomes super easy to keep your program logic clean. Put all the saving/loading stuff in the model classes. You can have your model classes listen for the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification and save when they receive it.

Unfortunately Apple's templates tend to push people toward putting a lot of stuff in app delegates or view controllers. Only really app global stuff should go in app delegate. Only controller code (that mediates between model and view) should go in a view controller.

Comment: You suggested that keep all the model data in separate classes, what are these separate classes? Controllers? Model controllers?

Comment: The data is stored in a model object (it is a 'model' of the data).  These classes often extend NSObject directly, but not always.  If you use Core Data then your model classes will extend NSManagedObject

Comment: The model classes can be anything. Whatever you app needs. If you were writing a recipe app, you might have two model classes - a list of recipes, and individual recipes. The list might be just an array, whereas the recipe might have things like a string for the name, an array of ingredients, an array of instructions, etc.  The main thing to think about is separating this from any other part of your app. Your view controller should not load the recipes, it should ask the model to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Inside other view controllers you do this

```
id myid = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Please replace the "id" with the name of your AppDelegate Class (usually AppDeletegate).

You of course have to #import the AppDelegate in the top of your implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to listen for UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification.

Also in iOS6 and later views are not unloaded when the memory is running low

> - (void)viewWillUnload Discussion In iOS 5 and earlier, when a low-memory condition occurred and the current view controller’s views
>     were not needed, the system could opt to remove those views from
>     memory. This method was called prior to releasing the actual views so
>     you could perform any cleanup prior to the view being deallocated. For
>     example, you could use this method to remove views as observers of
>     notifications or record the state of the views so it can be
>     reestablished when the views are reloaded.
>
> In iOS 6 and later, clearing references to views is no longer
>   necessary. As a result, any other cleanup related to those views, such
>   as removing them as observers, is also not necessary.